# 'pay' attribute is not recognized

Tags: python, class, methods, attributes

```
class Employee:
def __init__(self, first,last, pay):
    self.first=first
    self.last= last
    self.email=first+'.'+last+'@company.com'
def fullname(self):
    return '{} {}'.format(self.first,self.last)
def apply_rate(self):
    self.pay=int(self.pay * 1.04)   
emp_1=Employee('Rehim','Hesimov',50000)     
emp_2=Employee('Test','User',60000)     
print(emp_1.pay)
emp_1.apply_rate()
print(emp_1.pay)
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\rehim\Desktop\class.py", line 12, in ''
    print(emp_1.pay)
AttributeError: 'Employee' object has no attribute 'pay'
**Can anyone help me with this?**

Comment: The `__init__()` function does not assign `self.pay`.  Presumably you intended to do so.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're missing `self.pay = pay` from `__init__`.

Comment: I don't think this question requires an answer, a simple comment would've sufficed.